# Why I cannot reference constructor arguments inside of the class when defining object

Tags: kotlin

In this example `f` is unresolved when `bar` object is declared:

```
open class Bar(val b: Int)

class Foo(val f: Int) {
    object bar : Bar(f)
//                   ^
//         Unresolved reference: f

}
```

But when I declare `bar` as a variable, it works just fine:

```
open class Bar(val b: Int)

class Foo(val f: Int) {
    val bar = Bar(f)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I checked the Kotlin document about the Object keyword definition:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

There are two things, we need to know:

1. Object expression:

```
open class Bar(val b: Int)

    class Foo(val f: Int) {
        val bar = object : Bar(f) {
    }
}
```

It created an instance of an anonymous class that inherits from type `Bar`. And it is executed (and initialized) immediately.

2. Object declaration:

The singleton pattern, which can not have constructors.

```
open class Bar(val b: Int)  

object Foo {    
    fun create(val f: Int) : Bar {  
        return Bar(f)   
    }           
}
```

or companion object

```
open class Bar(val b: Int)

object Foo {
    fun create(val f: Int) : Bar {
        return Bar(f)
    }       
}
```

Ok, back to this question, I think what you want is the similar static variable in Java. Even in Java, you can't ref the un-static field object from the static field.

And don't use object in this way:

```
class Foo(val f: Int) {
    object bar : Bar(f)
}
```

which just declared an anonymous inner class, use ***companion object*** block instead, although it still can not ref outside variables.

Comment: So the way I'm defining object is same as defining companion object and according to documentation: "a companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved), matching the semantics of a Java static initializer", right?

Comment: Yeah, I guess what you need is companion object.

Comment: Why do you suggest to use `companion object`? It's effectively the same as using a regular object and you state yourself that it doesn't compile either.